# Activerecord - Group by a foreign key and return sum of another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, `Client` and `Project`. A `Client` `:has_many projects`. A `Project` has a `fee` column which is a dollar value. I'd like to develop an activerecord query that returns the 'Top Clients' with 'Top Clients' being the clients with the largest total value of combined project fees. Ideally the query would return an array of Client ID's in order of summed project value.

I've tried `Project.joins(:client).group('projects.id, client_id').sum(:fee)` which initially looks like it works, but the sum is incorrect and I can't figure out how to order it. Any suggestions on what this query should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion for your case above you can just group based client_id and then sum the fee and to the sort with method below, reverse will get you descending order

```
Project.group(:client_id).sum(:fee).sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse
```

if you need probably **top ten you can use first(10)**

```
Project.group(:client_id).sum(:fee).sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse.first(10)
```